# Why the order of \inputs is wrong at my final pdf?

Tags: bibliographies, floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

I have a simple single column scientific paper. The structure goes like this:

```
\begin{document}
\input{content}
\input{references}
\end{document}
```

the `references.tex` is this:

```
\bibliography{bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

The problem is that in the end of the content there are two tables and when I use `latextopdf` converter I have a PDF where in the end there are the references then one table then the rest of the references and then the other table. Why is that happening?

Comment: See: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017)

Comment: `table` and `figure` environment are *floats*. They are not positioned where you write them, but at specific positions (top, bottom of the current or a following page or one a page of their own). This is normally intended to get a good layout, but can be adjusted. See also [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275)